# bittorrent and utorrent current downloads just wiped after restart

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

so this has happened a couple of times , my pc hangs , then I have to manually reset it with the power button (it's a laptop) , then when I turn it on again , all of the settings of bittorrent or utorrent are just gone , I tried restoring them as there are settings and resumes .dat file renamed to .dat.old , but when I open the program it still pops empty and some of the files are again renamed to .dat.old, any way to fix this?

Comment: You might want to first consider **why** the machine is hanging in the first place.

Comment: that is not the problem , every once in a while the computer hangs , and it's not in my power to stop it , it's enough to try to open a corrupted save file from an application to continue your project , then you find out that this save is corrupted and causing the pc to hang , so it is out of my knowledge until trying to resume my work

Comment: not really. My computer hasn't hung more than twice since I got it, & I fixed that 6 years ago & it's been on 24/7 ever since, never sleeps, only reboots for OS updates. Ball is in your court, fix the underlying issue or try to mitigate the damage.

Comment: well I don't know where are you from , but I live in a country with no access to buy the original and legal versions of apps and games , so everything I use is pirated , and they have a tendency to not work as good as the original registered and intact versions , and I have no choice , and also we have some times power shortages and blackouts so these damage both the pc and files i'm working on, I can't fix something that has to do with my nationality and the country I live in , not that simple and cheap at least.

Comment: Ok people come and downvote for no reason, the question was clear, and no one that answered pointed out to any problems regarding the question. Also seems people downvoting on this site has no answer regarding a matter, but they still think the question was not necessary! this problem had happened to me for more than 2 years prior to the time I asked It. Also many people use torrents to share files, there are a lot of MMORPGs or multiplayer games offering their game-data on torrent services, so It is used for legal downloads.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that some programs (such as μtorrent) do not actually commit their settings changes until the program is shut down correctly.  I would suggest making your changes, exit the program, then restart it (confirming that the changes are still there).  You can at that point try a forced reboot of the computer to make sure that they will stay put after that as well.

Comment: well that is in case if the pc responds , but if I cant give the exit command what can I do then?

Comment: You would start on a fresh boot, make the changes and restart the app. If this is happening to new torrents you add, you may need to get in the habit of restarting μtorrent after each set of torrents is added, before it can crash again.

Comment: no , it happens to all of the torrents , all that haven't started yet , completed already or being downloaded , and they happen only when the pc is forced to restart/reset by the power button